# Failing LOAD DATA. No error gets returned, not records imported

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to import a file into my MySQL table. I have two problems.

## 1: No records are being imported

## 2  No error gets returned

I believe the first problem is that the file doesn't reside in the path. I am running this script in Wordpress. I know where the file is (buried in my uploads folder). But how can make the path relative to the file?

How can I get a correct error to be returned when this fails?

Thanks.

Comment: Try running the MySQL command outside of wordpress, with a function call like `mysqli_error()`. Then check for errors as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up testing in phpmyadmin to get the correct errors returned. Thanks.